# Как в preg_replace поместить $1 в глобальную переменную?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, переменные, php

Возможно ли сохранить внутреннюю переменную функции preg_replace в глобальную? То есть, когда производим замену:

```
$str = "time=21:00 index=12345 category=porno";
$format = preg_replace("/[бла бла бла]index=([0-9]*)[бла бла бла]/","$1",$str);
```

Вот на этом этапе как-нибудь можно сохранить отдельно то что попало в $1?

Нужно для того чтобы разбирая xml только регулярками, не отрубать всё лишнее в начале и в конце, оставшееся помещая в переменную, а как-нибудь иначе выковыривать нужное.

Например встречается <time>21:00</time>, и нужно выбрать только 21:00, при этом этот тег может лежать глубоко в середине большого дерева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модификатор /e меняет поведение функции preg_replace() таким образом, что параметр replacement после выполнения необходимых подстановок интерпретируется как PHP-код и только после этого используется для замены. Используя данный модификатор, будьте внимательны: параметр replacement должен содержать корректный PHP-код, в противном случае в строке, содержащей вызов функции preg_replace(), возникнет ошибка синтаксиса.

```
$str = "time=21:00 index=12345 category=porno";
$format = preg_replace("/index=([0-9]*)/e","($time=$1).$1",$str);
```

Примерно так это надо делать, но сначала надо сделать заглушку для $time=$1, например с помощью тернарного оператора.
Извините, не могу привести рабочий код, вчера нечаянно Windows снес, осталась голая Ubuntu с одним Eclipce :) Думаю у Вас получится реализовать это прочитав [источник](http://www.php.su/functions/?preg-replace)
**UPD**
рабочий пример

```
$str = "time=21:00 index=12345 category=porno";
$time=Array();
$format = preg_replace("/index=([0-9]*)/e","\$time[]='\\1'",$str);
print_r($time);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. :-) А ведь читала про этот модификатор, но не вчитывалась. :-)))

Answer (score 6):

Смотрите функцию **`preg_replace_callback`**.

---

Как-то так:

```
$index = 0;
function callback($match) {
    global $index;
    $index = $match[1];
    return $match[1];
}
$str = "time=21:00 index=12345 category=porno";
$format = preg_replace_callback("/[бла бла бла]index=([0-9]*)[бла бла бла]/","callback",$str);
echo $index; // 12345
```

Comment: Спасибо. Что-то сложно в понимании. В примерах всё вроде бы понятно, а на практике не понимаю как работает. :-)

Comment: Клёво. Тоже работает. Я блондинко, сначала возвращала $match[1] а потом пыталась присвоить глобальной переменной, хотя там уже нет ничего. Миллион спасибок. :-*

Comment: Жаль что exec не захочет со мной дружить. Такой мега-мозг друг мне нужен. :-)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, тебе сколько лет?

Comment: @exec Какой не культурный вопрос... Ну ладно..., мне чуть больше 20.